# crystal momentum conservation

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, interactions, tight-binding, strong-correlated

Electrons on 1D chain interacting with each other

$$ H = \sum_{k_4,k_3, k_2, k_1} V(k_4-k_1) c_{k_4}^{\dagger}c_{k_3}^{\dagger}c_{k_2}c_{k_1}\delta_{k4+k3=k2+k1;\text{mod}~G}$$
where $G$ is reciprocal lattice vector.

From how the above equation is derived, $H$ can also be written as

$$ H = \sum_{k_4,k_3, k_2, k_1} V(k_2-k_3) c_{k_4}^{\dagger}c_{k_3}^{\dagger}c_{k_2}c_{k_1}\delta_{k4+k3=k2+k1;\text{mod}~G}$$

But for some interaction,

$$ V(k_4-k_1)\neq V(k_2-k_3) $$

Then how is it possible for the two form of Hamiltonian to be equal? But they are equal mathematically.

---

Take G=10 as example to make this question clear. There should be a term:
$$V(7-3) c_{7}^{\dagger}c_{8}^{\dagger}c_{2}c_{3}$$
From the second form of Hamiltonian, there should be a term:
$$V(2-8) c_{7}^{\dagger}c_{8}^{\dagger}c_{2}c_{3}$$

But $V(7-3)\neq V(2-8)$.

Comment: Since momentum is conserved, $k_4+k_3\equiv k_1+k_2$. So $k_4-k_1\equiv k_2-k_3$ mod $G$. So $V(k_4-k_1)$ and $V(k_2-k_3)$ are the same thing if your interaction is translation invariant.

Comment: @MengCheng I did find some interaction $V(k+G)\neq V(k)$. For example nearest neighbor interaction of a A-B sublattice chain. What is your argument on such cases?

Comment: I remember you had some questions before about similar issues. I guess you are choosing unit cells so that $k/2$ appears somewhere. In the end of the day, physics is translation invariant, although the middle steps can be anything.